# ExcludeFromCodeCoverage not working at method level

Tags: .net-core, code-coverage, xunit.net

I have a .NET 6 Core C# application with XUnit-based unit tests and "XPlat Code Coverage"/Cobertura/Coverlet test coverage analysis. One method in an EF data context class that was flagged as missing some branch coverage is really only a hook for use by the testing framework itself so I marked it with the `ExcludeFromCodeCoverage` attribute.

It's still being reported as deficient in branch coverage. The coverage report itself mocks me by displaying

```
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
private void AdjustForTests(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    ...
```

while continuing to flag the branches as lacking in complete coverage. (`AdjustForTests` is called by `OnModelCreating`.)

This looks like it should be straightforward. `ExcludeFromCodeCoverage` always works for me when I apply it to a class. What might I be overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

Evidently it just doesn't work at the method level. The documentation says it applies to classes and structs. I had thought I'd read otherwise a long time ago, and the compiler doesn't flag an error, unfortunately.

Comment: It's kinda strange that an attribute that isn't honored at method level is even allowed to be used on a method, I would think the attribute would limit its usage to classes and types only. However, maybe the issue is not with the attribute, but with the code coverage tool, and that other coverage tools honors the attribute even down to method level.